# Como faço para listar pela data esse código aqui.?

Tags: java

É um for para adicionar os itens na jtable, e queria eles ordenados pela data para melhor visualização.

// Aqui tá o código:

```
for (Agenda agenda : listAg) {
            String data = sdf.format(agenda.getDataAgenda());
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{agenda.getFuncionario().getNomeFuncionario(), agenda.getCliente().getNomeCliente(), data, agenda.getStatus()});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser usado o método `sort` da classe `Collections`. Abaixo, segue uma das formas de uso do `sort`.

```
Collections.sort(listAg, new Comparator<Agenda>() {
  public int compare(Agenda o1, Agenda o2) {
      if (o1.getDataAgenda() == null || o2.getDataAgenda() == null)
        return 0;
      return o1.getDataAgenda().compareTo(o2.getDataAgenda());
  }
});
```

Para referência: [Class Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))